# Precedence in Spring Solr Query

Tags: spring, solr, spring-data, spring-data-solr

I am trying to get a Spring Solr query using a repository

> findByXOrYAndZ

The precedence should be as follows:

> (X OR Y) AND Z

I am using a SolrCrudRepository but I guess any of the repo would work.

How can I enforce this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could annotate the repository method with a `@Query` and give an arbitrary query to it.

For example:

```
@Query("fieldA:?0 AND (fieldB:?1 OR fieldC:?2)")
Page<Document> findByXOrYAndZ(String par1, String par2, String par3);
```

Comment: I would have preferred a solution with no @Query but this will do. Thanks!